# Update Excel file in the background with Interop and update linked books

Tags: c#, excel, office-interop

I have an Excel file (let's say Book1.xlsx) that is opened and updated by a C# application in the background using Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel and there is another Excel file (MainBook.xlsx )that refers to this book (Book1) through formulas.
The fact is that when Book1 is updated in the background, MainBook doesn't update the references until I open Book1 manually.

What should I do so that when the Book1 is updated, the changes are reflected in MainBook through the formulas it has.

Is it okay to use Workbook.UpdateLinks to achieve this? If so, how would you do it? Try this [Links in excel are not updating automatically C#](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20100139/links-in-excel-are-not-updating-automatically-c-sharp) and it does not work for me

Here is my Code to update Book1

```
Excel.Application excapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();         
excapp.Visible = false;

string workbookPath = @"Book1.xlsx";
var workbook = excapp.Workbooks.Open(workbookPath,
    3, false, 5, "", "", false, Excel.XlPlatform.xlWindows, "",
    true, false, 0, true, false, false);

var sheet = (Excel.Worksheet)workbook.Sheets[1]; 

sheet.Range["A:A"].Clear();
string cellName;
int counter = 1;
foreach (var item in list)
{

    cellName = "A" + counter.ToString();
    var range = sheet.get_Range(cellName, cellName);
    range.Value2 = item.ToString();
    ++counter;
}       

workbook.Save();
workbook.Close();
```

Comment: Any progress with this?

Comment: I solve it using OnTime method and call updateLinks in MainBook.xlsx https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/vba/excel-vba/articles/application-ontime-method-excel

Answer (score 0):

This is likely because you are opening up in a new instance of Excel with this line:

```
Excel.Application excapp = new Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application();
```

1) If you wish to have ***immediate*** formula updates, then you could open the Book 1 in the same instance. You need to use System.Runtime.InteropServices; for the Marshal class.

```
Excel.Application excapp = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application) 
                           Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");
string workbookPath = @"C:\MyFolder\Book1.xlsx";
....
```

This way would cause the Book1.xlsx to be visible though - if your current Excel instance(with Mainbook) is visible.

2) Another alternative is to use your existing code, and THEN call updateLink method on your mainbook after the code you have.

```
....
....

workbook.Save();
workbook.Close();

Excel.Application originalXLInstance = (Microsoft.Office.Interop.Excel.Application) 
                           Marshal.GetActiveObject("Excel.Application");

Workbook mainBook = originalXLInstance.Workbooks.Item["MainBook.xlsx"];
mainBook.UpdateLink(workbookPath, XlLinkType.xlLinkTypeExcelLinks);
```

workbookPath may need to be a full path of the Book1.xlsx file